# Facebook page linking to external site sign-up process, capture permission to write to wall in process?

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Have had a good hunt through the archive but can't find anyone trying to do this... hope someone familiar with the facebook API can confirm if it's possible?

Basically I have a client who wants to replicate their membership sign up process in a tab on their facebook page.
The form would still submit to their own website to process, we'd just be replicating the form fields.

As an additional requirement they want to capture peoples facebook user ID and get permission to post back to a users wall at the same time... The idea being that once the user is a member we can post back to their wall so their friends see that they've signed up...

Basically after a sanity check that:

1. these things are possible to do;
2. the best method to build the form in a FB page - I'm guessing using JS to create all fields & ajax to submit to the external site?

Comment: Can you even use JS on a FB page?

Answer (score 0):

I posted this a few days back, but I suppose the context is different. You'd just use the Facebook API in the same way.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
    'cookie' => false,
));

$facebook_login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'next' => '',
    'cancel_url' => '',
    'req_perms' => 'email,publish_stream,status_update'
));
```

You'd need to create a Facebook application, with the form on and attach the app to your page, if that makes sense?